# Oneplus One empty SD Card

Tags: android, ubuntu, cyanogenmod, oneplusone

I am a owner of a oneplus. Now I wanted to flash Ubuntu Phone on there. But I ended up having an total empty SD card with no system or files what so ever. the only thing that remains is the standard recovery.

What to do? I also tried to sideload CM12 on there so there would be atleast a OS on there.

Does anyone has an Idea how to solve this.

Kind regards,
FirePixel13

Comment: THis site is for programming questions.  You're off topic here.  I'm not sure what site you'd be on topic for, but it definitely doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2751647

Download three files:

```
recovery.img
boot.img
system.img
```

Plug your phone into your computer and bring up a command prompt.

Navigate to the folder where you saved the above files.

Issue these commands one line at a time, waiting for each to finish before proceeding to the next:

```
adb reboot bootloader
sudo fastboot flash boot boot.img
sudo fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
sudo fastboot erase system
sudo fastboot flash system system.img
```

Then restart your phone.